# Calculate total in SQL from two different rows by date

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, window-functions

I have a table with: date, daily_count and total_count and total_count is empty and has to be calculated with MySQL. Date and daily_count are known and I want to calculate today's total_count from daily_count(today) + total count(yesterday).

I can calculate it with:

```
SELECT t2.daily_count + t1.total_count total 
 FROM mytbl t1, mytbl t2 
 WHERE t1.date = '2020-2-27' AND t2.date = '2020-2-28'
```

How can I do that at once for a table with more than one year of data and with only date en daily count. So all the total_counts have to be calculated. And later I want to UPDATE the total into total_count in mytbl. Or do I have two write down all the 365 SQL lines with different dates for one year of data?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this easily with window functions:

```
select date, daily_count, sum(daily_count) over(order by date) total_count
from mytbl
```

You can turn this to an `update` query as follows (assuming that `date` is a unique column):

```
update mybtl t
inner join (
    select date, sum(daily_count) over(order by date) total_count
    from mytbl
) t1 on t1.date = t.date
set t.total_count = t1.total_count
```

Answer (score -1):

For cumulative sum you can do the following:

```
SET @t=0;
SELECT daily_count,@t:=@t+daily_count FROM mytbl ORDER BY mytbl.date;
```

Same can be done with update as well. Use `ORDER BY` to ensure correct processing order.

```
SET @t=0;
UPDATE mytbl SET total_count=@t:=@t+daily_count ORDER BY mytbl.date;
```